# No feedback when comment fails to post on Android 2.3.5

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, usability

In the mobile theme on Android 2.3.5, comments that do not meet the minimum length will fail to post but no feedback message is displayed to the user.  The submit button changes to its active state, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Good point; I personally *know* why it happens when it does, so I've never thought of it as a bug. However, not all users will have any idea why it's failing, so it'll confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue with the current mobile themes and sites. If it remains, please let me know!