# Unable to add comments to questions and answers from an Android device

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, mobile-web

I have HTC Explorer which runs on Android 2.3.5 Gingerbread operating system. From the very first day, I have been unable to add comments to questions or answers (I have enough reputation to comment anywhere).

Is this just happening to me or the comments are disabled from Android devices?

Comment: Please define/explain: `unable to add comments`

Comment: I am unable to click the add comment anchor. When I click, nothing happens

Comment: declining as we only support latest 2 versions of browsers (I assume this is older than that given that the current Android version is 4 versions later)

Answer (score 2):

No, comments are not disabled from Android devices in general; I just tested using the default browser in Android 2.2 and also with [Dolphin browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser), on Android 4.0.3, and I had no problem adding a comment, or editing it. (*Was your comment at least 15 characters?*)

Only, I was not able to delete a comment, I had to switch to desktop version for that(with Dolphin is really easy to do that).

My recommandation is to **try another browser**, and see if you problem still persist.

Comment: I am unable to click on add comment anchor. Nothing happens at all. I also have the dolfin browser installed but that too doesn't do anything when the link is clicked

Comment: And you are sure your comment is it [least 15 characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119357/no-feedback-when-comment-fails-to-post-on-android-2-3-5?rq=1)? Because I experienced the same thing while trying to post just a 'test' comment.

Comment: The question of 15 word limit will arise if I am able to click the **add comment** anchor